# Android logcat - I do not understand the error

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

I debug my program in Android studio but it didn't work; then I couldn't understand the logcat. Could you help me finding the problem?

Logcat:

```
02-19 12:14:55.333    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-19 12:14:55.349    2300-2306/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-19 12:14:55.409    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
02-19 12:14:55.413    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11344: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
02-19 12:14:55.413    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
02-19 12:14:55.421    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
02-19 12:14:55.421    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11350: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-19 12:14:55.421    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
02-19 12:14:55.433    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
02-19 12:14:55.433    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9038: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
02-19 12:14:55.437    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
02-19 12:14:55.437    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-19 12:14:55.441    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-19 12:14:55.441    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-19 12:14:55.441    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-19 12:14:55.441    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 386: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-19 12:14:55.441    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-19 12:14:55.481    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-19 12:14:55.481    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb97125e0, tid 2300
02-19 12:14:55.493    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-19 12:14:55.493    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-19 12:14:55.521    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-19 12:14:55.525    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-19 12:14:55.529    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-19 12:14:55.529    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-19 12:14:55.537    2300-2303/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 184K, 3% free 9001K/9212K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 7ms
02-19 13:24:24.077    2300-2300/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-19 13:41:03.709    2300-2306/com.example.oem.mysql_test2 D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

Comment: What your program do? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

The method ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll() requires API level 21 (Android 5.0).
Therefore you need a device or an emulator image that uses Android 5.